# BindableProperty List doesn't change

Tags: c#, xamarin, collections, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a custom TabbedView however the bindable property wont change when I add some CustomTab trough a xaml page.

What is wrong in the code bellow?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TabsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Tabs", typeof(List<CustomTab>), typeof(TabbedView), new List<CustomTab>(), BindingMode.Default, null, TabsPropertyChanged, TabsPropertyChanging);

public List<CustomTab> Tabs
{
    get
    {
        return (List<CustomTab>)GetValue(TabsProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(TabsProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged("Tabs");
    }
}

private static void TabsPropertyChanging(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
}

private static void TabsPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
}
```

XAML

```
<pageComponents:TabbedView x:Name="myTabs">
    <pageComponents:TabbedView.Tabs>
        <pageComponents:CustomTab></pageComponents:CustomTab>
        <pageComponents:CustomTab></pageComponents:CustomTab>
        <pageComponents:CustomTab></pageComponents:CustomTab>
    </pageComponents:TabbedView.Tabs>
</pageComponents:TabbedView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Change your BindableProperty definition to something like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TabsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Tabs), 
    typeof(IEnumerable),
    typeof(TabbedView));
```

As Clay indicated you don't want your collection instance to be set from the outside so change your Property to something like:

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomTab> Tabs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomTab>();
```

In your constructor subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` and use that method to be notified when your collection changes (new items added).

```
public TabbedView()
{
    Tabs.CollectionChanged += OnTabsChanged;
}
```

Your Event Handler

```
 private void OnTabsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     // Do here what you need to do
 }
```

Tip:

If you set the `ContentProperty` as the `Tabs` property you could add Tabs in XAML without having to specify the Tag.

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Tabs))]
public partial class TabbedView : ContentView
{
   ...
}
```

Then in your XAML this would be sufficient

```
<pageComponents:TabbedView>
        <pageComponents:CustomTab />
        <pageComponents:CustomTab />
        <pageComponents:CustomTab />
</pageComponents:TabbedView>
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: use 
`public ObservableCollection<CustomTab> Tabs => (ObservableCollection<CustomTab>) GetValue(TabsProperty);` 
instead 
`public ObservableCollection<CustomTab> Tabs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomTab>();`

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
First - You don't want to actually *set* the list but only add to it in xaml, so just make a getter and initialize it.
Second - the List needs to be observable so the view will update when something is added or removed.

This should do what you want:

```
public IList<CustomTab> Tabs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomTab>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try it like this:

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=netstandard"
...
<pageComponents:TabbedView x:Name="myTabs">
    <pageComponents:TabbedView.Tabs>
       <s:List x:TypeArguments="pageComponents:CustomTab"> 
          <pageComponents:CustomTab></pageComponents:CustomTab>
          <pageComponents:CustomTab></pageComponents:CustomTab>
          <pageComponents:CustomTab></pageComponents:CustomTab>
       </s:List>
    </pageComponents:TabbedView.Tabs>
</pageComponents:TabbedView>
```